# Is file_put_contents secure to upload files

Tags: php, file-upload, file-put-contents

I am using `file_put_contents()` function to write the files on server. I have split the file on client side and send chunks on server. using file_put_contents I am writing that content on server side file.

So I worry, is that a secure way to do it?

Comment: 1. file from upload form or file_get_contents? 2. how big the filesize?

Comment: 1. file upload from form in client side and i split it in small parts and then upload on server and server side i write that small part in single file on server using file_get_contents.

Comment: 2. There is not limit now but i will put it.

Comment: we have same problem. i use plupload that allow me to chunck upload .sorry  cant help you much with selfcoding php to upload big data

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to allow files to be written securely.
Make a location outside server root directory.
Something like:
root dir = /htdocs/html/

Data dir = /htdocs/data/

That way the web server does not have direct access to the files.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what possible attack done to file_get_contents.

Comment: 1. Remote code execution.
2. Sql injection.
3. Cross site scripting.
and more ways to this.